# Difference in package importing between Python 2.7 and 3.4

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, package, python-3.4

For this directory hierarchy:

```
.
├── hello
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── world
│       └── __init__.py
└── test.py
```

And the Python source files:

#### test.py:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import hello
```

#### hello/__init__.py:

```
import world
```

#### hello/world/__init__.py:

```
print("yes you win")
```

Running test.py with Python 3.4 throws `ImportError` saying that module `world` is not found, but with Python 2.7 everything is fine.

I know that `sys.path` is referenced when searching for the imported modules, so adding the directory `hello` to `sys.path` eliminates the error.

But in Python 2.7, before importing `world`, the directory `hello` is not in `sys.path` either. What causes this difference? Is there any recursive searching policy applied in Python 2.7?

Comment: [See PEP 328.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Python 3 uses absolute imports (see [PEP 328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) as @user2357112 points out).  The short of it is that Python 3 searches from the root of each `sys.path` entry, rather than first consulting the module's directory as if it were a prepended entry in `sys.path`.

To get the behavior you want you can either:

- Use relative imports explicitly: `from . import world` in the `hello` package
- Use an absolute import: `import hello.world`

Comment: Yes I've read the PEP. I read in the document of Python 2.7 about the module searching path ([here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path)). In my example, running `test.py` will add the dot (`.`) directory to `sys.path`, but not the directory containing `world`, then how can the Python 2.7 interpreter find the package `world`?

Comment: `world` is a *package*. Python treats the package directory `world` identically to the module `world.py` in the same directory (at least as far as we are concerned here).  The fact that `__init__.py` is being loaded from *inside* world is irrelevant to the case.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes it helps. Perhaps the best way is to read the code. Thanks :)

Comment: Is `import .world` even a valid syntax in python 3? I think you should do `from . import world`.