# No module named api_core.protobuf_helpers. python2.7 and googlecloud

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-cloud-speech

I am trying [the following example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/speech/cloud-client/beta_snippets.py) to test the translation with language auto detection.

It works fine with python3.

But when trying with python2.7 it fails with the following message:

```
python2.7 example.py multi-language
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "google_example.py", line 295, in <module>
    transcribe_file_with_multilanguage()
  File "google_example.py", line 214, in transcribe_file_with_multilanguage
    from google.cloud import speech_v1p1beta1 as speech
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/speech_v1p1beta1/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from google.cloud.speech_v1p1beta1 import types
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/speech_v1p1beta1/types.py", line 20, in <module>
    from google.api_core.protobuf_helpers import get_messages
ImportError: No module named api_core.protobuf_helpers
```

Output of `pip2 freeze | grep google`:

```
google==2.0.2 
google-api-core==1.8.0
google-auth==1.6.3 
google-cloud-core==0.29.1 
google-cloud-speech==0.36.3 
googleapis-common-protos==1.6.0b9
```

Comment: Python 2 and 3 import differently. You can read more about it in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30249119/difference-in-package-importing-between-python-2-7-and-3-4).

Comment: You might be running it with an [old version](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/speech/index.html#changelog) of the `google-cloud-speech` library. Could you share the result of the command `pip2 freeze | grep google`? And for Guido's sake stop using `Python2.7` it's been more than 10 years from the first  `Python3` version release.

Comment: This is the output :
google==2.0.2
google-api-core==1.8.0
google-auth==1.6.3
google-cloud-core==0.29.1
google-cloud-speech==0.36.3
googleapis-common-protos==1.6.0b9

Comment: I would love to use python3 but I have other libraries that work only with python2.7 and I do not want to do system calls but have everything in python....

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a conflict between package names. As you have the [`google` package](https://pypi.org/project/google/) installed your environment is trying to fetch the `api_core.protobuf_helpers` module from it instead of from `google-api-core`.

To overcome this issue, take the approach of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42275036/7757976). Uninstall the `google` package and reinstall it with a different name.

Also note that you are using a [beta pre-release](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#pre-releases) of the [`googleapis-common-protos` python. library](https://pypi.org/project/googleapis-common-protos/#history). If you want to use the current stable version run:

```
pip2 uninstall googleapis-common-protos
pip2 install googleapis-common-protos==1.5.8
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone! I followed the recommendation and uninstalled all the google python modules. I reinstalled them again in the following order. 
The order I followed is:

```
sudo pip2 install google 
sudo pip2 install google-api-core 
sudo pip2 install google-auth 
sudo pip2 install google-cloud-core 
sudo pip2 install google-cloud-speech 
sudo pip2 install googleapis-common-protos
```

Now it works:
{

```
python2.7 interpreter.py multi-language
Waiting for operation to complete...
--------------------
First alternative of result 0: transcript: "hello how are you"
confidence: 0.984296917915
```

}